# Porque no se aplica JQuery?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

En una página (index.php) tengo un div ('#cuerpo'), dentro de este cuerpo cargo contenido mediante ajax.

Mi problema es que tengo cuando cargo opciones.php dentro de #cuerpo, jquery no funciona, pero si en el navegador cargo directamente opciones.php jquery si me funciona.

La libreria jquery he probado a ponerla en index.php y en opciones.php, pero aun asi no me funciona jquery, ¿alguien me da la respuesta?

El siguiente codigo es lo que contiene "opciones.php", y como digo, si lo muestro dentro de #cuerpo no funciona jquery.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
<style type="text/css">
 #opciones{
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #d1d1d1;
 }
 #editar{
  width: 300px;
  height: 120px;
  background: pink;
 }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $("#editar").hide();
 });

 function editar_opciones(){
  $("#editar").show();
  $("#opciones").hide();
 }

 function actualizar_opciones(){
  $("#editar").hide();
  $("#opciones").show();
 }

</script>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="opciones">
  Nombre: Vemos opciones<br>
  <button onclick="editar_opciones()">Editar</button>
 </div>
 <div id="editar">
  Nombre: Editamos opciones
  <button onclick="actualizar_opciones()">Ver</button>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: El código incluído no tiene un div con id=cuerpo

Comment: Puedes intentar meter todo en un `${body}.on('click', function(){})`. Cuando se crean los elementos con ajax no tienen eventos asignados. Con `.on` cada vez que des click en el body se ejecutara la función.

Comment: Por otro lado al usar Stack Snippet deberías colocar cada tipo de código en el panel que le corresponde. En cuanto al html no hace falta que incluyas las etiquetas DOCTYPE, head, body y html pues estas son agregadas por la página de la pregunta.

Comment: el div#cuerpo está en el index.php, este archivo(opciones.php) es un archivo externo que se mostrará con ajax dentro del index.php#cuerpo

Comment: Lo curioso es que en #cuerpo cargo otros archivos y en esos archivos si me funciona jquery, pero con opciones.php no

Comment: Crea un [mcve] con el código del index.php y agrégalo a la pregunta.

Answer (score 0):

intenta usar

```
$( "#cuerpo" ).load( "opciones.php" );
```

Si vienen scripts dentro de la respuesta se ejecutarán.

http://api.jquery.com/load/